# Excel VBA address of FIRST INSTANCE instead of address of each location of value

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have a few employee numbers listed in Sheet1 of a workbook.  There are a few other sheets (lets call these sheets A, B, C, D, etc) in the workbook that contain the employee number with some info (maybe dates worked).  If an employee number is found in, lets say, worksheet A, it will not be in any other worksheet, but it may appear multiple time within worksheet A.

I wrote some VBA that will look in all other worksheets for the employee number listed in Sheet1 and return the cell location of where that employee number is found.  Employee numbers are listed in column A, starting at A2 and it listls the location of where the number is found to the right of the employee number.
[How Sheet1 looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqNPH.png)
[Sheet "A"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eETWQ.png)

Right Now, when I run my VBA Macro, it will list all the cell location of where that employee number is found, but what i want it do it is give me the cell location of only the FIRST INSTANCE of that employee number.  Then, move on to the next employee number listed in colmn A of Sheet1. This is the VBA I have so far.

```
Sub makeMySearch()
Dim ws As Worksheet, lastrow As Long

For Each cell In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row)
    recFound = 0

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
            lastrow = Sheets(ws.Name).Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
            For Each cell2 In Sheets(ws.Name).Range("A1:A" & lastrow)

                If InStr(cell2.Value, cell.Value) <> 0 Then

                    recFound = recFound + 1
                    cell.Offset(0, recFound) = Split(cell2.Address, "$")(1) & Split(cell2.Address, "$")(2)

                End If
            Next cell2
        End If
    Next ws
Next cell

MsgBox "Done Finding!"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This method will stop on the first find (via the `Exit For`)

It also shows a more efficient method rather than looping all the cells on each sheet

```
Sub makeMySearch()
    Dim cell  As Range, cell2 As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lastrow As Long, recFound As Long
    Dim rw As Variant
    Dim dat As Variant, i As Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        dat = .Range(.Cells(2,1), .Cells(.Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp)).Value
        For i = 1 To UBound(dat, 1)
            For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
                If ws.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
                    rw = Application.Match( dat(i, 1) , ws.Columns(1), 0)
                    If Not IsError(rw) Then
                        .Cells(i+1, 2) = "A" & rw
                        ' Option: show Sheet name and cell
                        '.Cells(i+1, 2) = ws.Name & "!A" & rw
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next ws
        Next
    End With

    MsgBox "Done Finding!"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response!  I really appreciate your help, but this isn't quite doing the trick.  When I ran your code it is only searching for what is in Cell A:1 of Sheet 1.  I need it to search for each employee number listed in Column A (starting on row 2) of Sheet1.

Comment: @user6896503 that is what it's doing.  Both my code and yours relies on certain layout of data in column A of Sheet1.  Just to verify that layout can you update your Q with some sample data from Sheet1 and one of the other sheets.

Comment: I updated it and added 2 pictures.  One shows what the search sheet looks like and the other shows what the data in the other sheets look like.  I worked with VBA years ago (haven't since) and was only a beginner, so I'm pretty much reteaching it to myself.

Comment: Ok, there is nothing unexpected there, code should work.  Couple of small tweeks possible though

Comment: Changed End Down to EndUp and removed wild cards

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying Column A on Sheet1 is a heading row and the data starts on row 2 you just need to edit the following line:

dat = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown)).Value

to be:

dat = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown)).Value